# Jar with multiple main

Tags: java, jar, server, client, program-entry-point

In one package I have two different classes Client.java and Server.java
I want to make this package jar, i mean executable.
First I want the Server class to run and after 2-3 seconds I want Client method to run. Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: start with a single Main class and then wait it to execute completely or sleep for some seconds or spawn a new Thread based on your requirements which will invoke the main method of other classes.Never heard of a classe having more than 1 main method.

Comment: Sounds like a multithreading problem to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to leave only one main method and run your server and client in separate threads from it.

To do it, take a look at [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface. Your server class and client class should implement it. Then you have to move the logic, used to start server and client to it's `run()` method.

```
class Server implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your server starting logic here
    }
}

class Client implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your client starting logic here
    }
}
```

After that, you can modify your `main` method, to start server and client, like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    Server server = new Server();
    Client client = new Client();

    Thread tServer = new Thread(server);
    tServer.start();

    //here you can wait some time to Server started

    Thread tClient = new Thread(client);
    tClient.start();
}
```